# Configure Apple Mail to always open calendar invites in Fantastical 2

Tags: mail.app, email, calendar, ical

How can I configure Apple Mail to always open calendar invites in Fantastical 2?

Typically in OS X dialogs, you'd:

- Right click on file
- Select `Open With...`
- Choose the application
- Select `Always open files of this type` option

However, this option isn't available in the Mail dialog.

How do I set this preference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OS X Default calendar app preference is set in Calendar.app's preferences. If you select Fantastical there it should yield the behavior you are looking for.

Calendar.app > Calendar > Preferences > General > Default Calendar App

Comment: It doesn't "take" for me. I have set this but every time I close calendar.app and re-open it, is has changed the default back to itself.